# Php replace and concat

Tags: php, replace, concatenation

I need to replace and concat some values in a random string, i store the values in an array.

**I.e.**

```
$search = array('dog', 'tree', 'forest', 'grass');
$randomString = "A dog in a forest";
```

If one or more array values matches the random string then i need a replace like this:

```
$replacedString = "A @dog in a @forest";
```

Can someone help me?

Thx.

Comment: READ the doc of [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php) please.

Answer (score 8):

```
foreach (explode(' ', $randomString) as $word) {
  $replacedString .= in_array($word, $search) ? "@$word " : "$word ";
}

echo $replacedString;  // A @dog in a @forest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($search as $word)
{
  $randomString = str_replace($word,"@".$word,$randomString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do correctly but have a look at [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

and try something like

```
foreach($search as $string)
{
    $replacement[] = "@".$search;
}

$new_string = str_replace($search, $replacement, $randomString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$words = explode(" ", $randomString);

foreach($words as $word){
   if(in_array($word, $search)){
      $word = "@$word";
   }
}

$replacedString = implode(" ", $words);
```